# Tomcat Project and Eclipse WTP Remote Server

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, eclipse-wtp

I am just starting out with programming a tomcat server in java, and have installed eclipse's Web Tools Platform, but when I try to create a Dynamic Web Project, It wants me to specify an installation of Tomcat on my own machine. Is it necessary, other than to run the project, as the server to really use it is online? If it's not, any way I can bypass this problem?

(I'm not sure if there us a more appropriate stack exchange site for this: If there is, please direct me to it.)

Comment: In addition to allowing you to debug your project, this allows eclipse to test your project for compliance. If you don't want to specify an installation, you could create some other kind of project.

Comment: In case you are not super-smart servlet developer, you are going to need to debug, cross-check and rectify errors on your local machine before deploying war on the server.  The only way to bypass is to write code in some other editor , create war from command prompt and deploy on server, and I guess you won't like to do it.